# Problems with package install in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install some basic packages in R, but it shows me this message:

```
> install.packages("rmarkdown")
Warning in install.packages :
'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"' is not writable
Warning in install.packages :
cannot create dir 'C:\Users\׳׳׳¢׳“', reason 'Permission denied'
Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘C:/Users/׳׳׳    
¢׳“/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
```

I tried to change the folder to writable, but it did not help. Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/tobigithub/R-parallel/wiki/R-parallel-Errors). Says you need to run R as an administrator. Hope it works!

> **Solution:** Packages under Windows 7, Win8, Win10 need to be installed into a user directory (C:\R\R-3.2.2), or R needs to be started as Administrator (in start menu or Explorer use mouse right-click, then run as administrator).